# Decimal value in Polymer core-range

Tags: polymer

How to input decimal value in core-range, as in given [demo](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-range/demo.html)?

With 'step' attribute added:

```
<core-range step="0.5"  min="0" max="200" value="{{value}}" ratio="{{ratio}}"></core-range>
```

I can paste decimal(e.g. 5.5) in the input field but cannot type it?!

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty interesting. I think it's a bug in the core-range element itself (https://github.com/Polymer/core-range/blob/master/core-range.html). As the input gets validated "5." gets overwritten by the number 5 and set as value. Since it is reflected in the input field itself, the input changes to 5. When you paste it in as a whole, the "5.5" stays and is reflected in the input field. That's why it works when you paste it. I don't think there's a work around other than fixing the bug.

Issue opened:
https://github.com/Polymer/core-range/issues/2